# Finding the volume of the pyramid and also determining the increase and decrease of its volume

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

The volume of a pyramid with a square base $x$ units on a side and a height of $h$ is $V=\dfrac{1}{3}x^2h$

1) Suppose $x=e^t$ and $h=e^{-2t}$. Use the chain rule to find $V^1(t)$.

2) Does the volume of the pyramid increase or decrease as $t$ increases.

My Try:

From the question $V=\dfrac{1}{3}x^2h$, $x=e^t$ and $h=e^{-2t}$

$V=\dfrac{1}{3}e^{2t}e^{-2t}$

$V^1(t)=\dfrac{1}{3}$

But when I tried it in Symbolab the derivative was $0$ i.e $V^1(t)=0$

How to proceed with the above problem.

Can anyone explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V=\frac{1}{3}e^{2t}e^{-2t}=\frac{1}{3}e^{2t-2t}=\frac{1}{3}e^{0}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Thus $V'(t)=0$. But if you insist on using the chain rule then, we apply the product rule and then the chain rule

$V'=-\frac{2}{3}e^{2t}e^{-2t}+\frac{2}{3}e^{2t}e^{-2t}=0$.

Clearly the volume of the pyramid clearly is a constant so doesn't increase or decrease.

Comment: So, should I consider the volume to $0$ or $\dfrac{1}{3}$

Comment: The volume is $\frac{1}{3}$, and the derivative is $0$.